# submit button in oracle jdeveloper 11g

Tags: oracle11g, jdeveloper, oracle-adf, oracle-xe

I am using oracle jdeveloper and i am inserting rows by insert button but its response is strange as it is updating last record in the data base instead of creating new record.and one thing is more it is not updating in the real data base....

Comment: Please describe in details how you are trying to do it. Show your code.

Comment: not sure what you are talking about. What insert button. Are you using ADF Faces?

Comment: I am using jdeveloper xe database and making adf application and using panel tabbed in the form layout...Actually I am new in jdeveloper....

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a createInsert operation to your page? Did you add a commit operation to the page?
If you are just starting I would suggest first going through this tutorial that will show you the basics of creating these types of applications - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_55/jdtut_11r2_55_1.html

Comment: I have followed this tutotiral but at the end same problem exist....I am adding commit button but after submit button commit button goes automatically disabled.I also its property according to information available on internet but i cant find any solution.....

Comment: For the commit button just set the disabled property to false and it will be enabled.